# How to change windows os selection titles in dual boot

Tags: windows, multi-boot

Don't know how to ask, so adding print-screen.

[image: OS Select]

I want to have some different titles instead of `Windows 8.1` that would be more clear which-one is which-one. Does anyone knows how to achieve this?

Thanks!

P.S. I would like to find solution which doesn't require third party software.

Comment: I've added the BCDedit commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/), go to the Advanced Settings" tab

[image]

select the Windows you want to edit and here you can rename the entry (entry: NAME):

[image]

If you prefer onboard tools you have to use BCDedit:

```
bcdedit /set {GUID} description "My 2. Windows 8.1"
```

Run `BCDedit /v` to get all GUIDs for the start entries.

Answer (score 0):

It is even easier with [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net).

Click on entry to rename (to select it) then "F2" key to rename (as in Explorer) ;)
[image: Visual BCD Editor v.0.9.3]